# Uncheck the JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jcheckbox

How can I uncheck the `JCheckBox`?

I am making a GUI in which I want to uncheck the selected check box after click on the "Add" button. What I am doing when I select the check box and display name will be add in to array list `Panel.Arr`. After click on Add button selected check boxes added in to the "List of the image to be imported panel".

I want that when selected check box add in to "Image to be imported panel", the selected check box becomes unchecked/disabled. So that user will not select again once its add in to the "Image to be imported panel"

I am pasting the snapshot of my GUI so that you can understand easily.

[image]

and I am also pasting my checkbox display code and add button code
//checkbox display code

```
{       
int space=30;
// create a check button (for selection) for each target resource
for (int i=0; i < images.size(); i++) {
    ResourceListObject resource = images.get(i);

    // create the radio button for this target
    t = new JCheckBox(resource.getName() + ", " + resource.getOID());
    t.addActionListener(this);
    t.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
    t.setName(""+i);
    t.setActionCommand(resource.getName()+"_"+resource.getOID());
    t.setBounds(13, space,355, 23);
    t.setVisible(true);
    panel.add(t);
    space=space+25;
    // add the virtual target to the target group, then to the panel
}
```

//Add button code

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add >>");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(437, 312, 100, 23);
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {

             Volume_ID_Image_tmp = restEngine.getimageContent(Panel.Arr);
             try {
                  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                ImportImagePanel  jsonobj = new ImportImagePanel(Volume_ID_Image_tmp,panel_1,"add");
        } catch (IOException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
            }

          Volume_ID_Image.addAll(Volume_ID_Image_tmp); 
          Volume_ID_Image_tmp.clear(); 

       }           
   });
    frmToolToMigrate.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
```

Comment: You should place the `JCheckBox`s in some kind of list and runback through the list and update their selected state

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I am little bit familiar with java. I would be great if you can explain in detail.

Comment: You meant that comment for @MadProgrammer ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ohh, no they didn't ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Well, I was really just guessing, given their appeal to me to churn out code was going to 'fall on deaf ears'.  :P

Comment: yeah i mean for @MadProgrammer :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, you can use `t.setSelected(false)`. That'll make the JCheckBox unchecked.